# For duplicate values in an array, how do I use "repeat" with Ramda.js

Tags: ramda.js

I am trying to duplicate `target:[ "a", "b", "c"]` with `count:[1, 2, 3]`

Desirable output is `["a", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c"]`

It's not working with this code :

```
const fn = ({ target, count }) => R.map (R.repeat (target, count))

const Data = { target : ["a", "b", "c"], count : [1, 2, 3] }

const result = fn(Data)
```

I am trying to find solution with Ramda.js.

Thanks.

Comment: There might be a better way, but I think `R.chain(R.apply(R.repeat), R.zip (target, count))` works.

Comment: @user3297291 Well, it certainly works. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to catch arguments in "R.applySpec" : Ramda.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347188/unable-to-catch-arguments-in-r-applyspec-ramda-js)

Comment: Not exactly. I used the same code base, but the issue is different. I could not use the same technique to solve these issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another fairly simple solution:

```js
const fn = ({target, count}) => 
  unnest (zipWith (repeat) (target, count))

const data = {
  target: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
  count: [1, 2, 3]
}

console .log (fn (data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {unnest, zipWith, repeat} = R                             </script>
```

A point-free function of `target` and `data` is easy enough:

```js
compose (unnest, zipWith (repeat))
```

If they are wrapped in an object and you really want point-free, then the answer from Hitmands seems best, or a variant using this technique:

```js
compose (unnest, apply (zipWith (repeat)), props (['target', 'count']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like the following:

```js
const fn = R.pipe(
  R.props(['target', 'count']),
  R.apply(R.zip),
  R.chain(R.apply(R.repeat)),
);
  

// ===

const data = { 
  target : ["a", "b", "c"], 
  count : [1, 2, 3],
}

console.log(
  fn(data),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Ah, now, I can associate your answer with the following question. Thanks!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64347188/unable-to-catch-arguments-in-r-applyspec-ramda-js