# Unable to catch arguments in "R.applySpec" : Ramda.js

Tags: ramda.js

I am basically trying to achieve the code below within the `R.applySpec`.

```
const fn = ({target, count}) => R.unnest (R.zipWith (R.repeat) (target, count))

const Data = { 
  target : ["a", "b", "c"], 
  count : [1, 2, 3],
}

const data1= {
  result : fn (Data)
}
console.log ( 'data1:', data1.result);// ["a","b","b","c","c","c"]
```

What I cannot figure out is that arguments in the `fn` seems to be uncaught within the `R.applySpec`

```
const data2_applySpec = R.applySpec({
  result : R.lift ( R.zipWith ( fn )) ( R.prop ('target'),  R.prop ('count'))
})

const data2 = data2_applySpec(Data)
console.log ('data2:', data2);//ERROR
```

How can I alter the `fn` to make it work?
I use Ramda.js.
Thanks.

[REPL](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?%0Aconst%20fn1%20%3D%20%28%7Btarget%2C%20count%7D%29%20%3D%3E%20unnest%20%28zipWith%20%28repeat%29%20%28target%2C%20count%29%29%0A%0Aconst%20Data%20%3D%20%7B%20%0A%20%20target%20%3A%20%5B%22a%22%2C%20%22b%22%2C%20%22c%22%5D%2C%20%0A%20%20count%20%3A%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst%20data1%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20result%20%3A%20fn1%20%28Data%29%0A%7D%0Aconsole.log%20%28%20%27data1%3A%27%2C%20data1.result%29%3B%2F%2F%20%5B%22a%22%2C%22b%22%2C%22b%22%2C%22c%22%2C%22c%22%2C%22c%22%5D%0A%0A%0Aconst%20data2_applySpec%20%3D%20applySpec%28%7B%0A%20%20result%20%3A%20lift%20%28%20zipWith%20%28%20fn1%20%29%29%20%28%20prop%20%28%27target%27%29%2C%20%20prop%20%28%27count%27%29%29%0A%7D%29%0A%0Aconst%20data2%20%3D%20data2_applySpec%28%20Data%29%0Aconsole.log%20%28%20%27data4%3A%27%2C%20data4%29%3B%2F%2FERROR%0A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're making this harder than it needs to be.

You already have the function you want to use inside `applySpec` stored as `fn`.

So you can just write:

```js
const fn2 = applySpec ({
  result: fn
})
```

Or, if your only use of `fn` is inside this `applySpec` call, then just inline it:

```js
const fn3 = applySpec ({
  result: ({target, count}) => unnest (zipWith (repeat) (target, count))
})
```

And if you have a fetish for point-free code, you can use the technique discussed in your [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64335821):

```js
const fn4 = applySpec ({
  result: compose (unnest, apply (zipWith (repeat)), props (['target', 'count']))
})
```

(or the similar version from Ori Drori.)

All of these are shown in this snippet.

```js
const fn1 = ({target, count}) => unnest (zipWith (repeat) (target, count))

const fn2 = applySpec ({
  result: fn1
})

const fn3 = applySpec ({
  result: ({target, count}) => unnest (zipWith (repeat) (target, count))
})

const fn4 = applySpec ({
  result: compose (unnest, apply (zipWith (repeat)), props (['target', 'count']))
})


const data = {target : ["a", "b", "c"], count : [1, 2, 3]}

console .log (fn1 (data))
console .log (fn2 (data))
console .log (fn3 (data))
console .log (fn4 (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {unnest, zipWith, repeat, applySpec, compose, apply, props} = R </script>
```

Comment: Thanks to your help, I have a better understanding of applySpec. The explanations that carefully unraveled are very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can can an array of arrays ([target, count]) using `R.props`, apply the array of array to `R.zipWith(repeat)`, and then flatten the results with `R.unnest`:

```js
const { applySpec, pipe, props, apply, zipWith, repeat, unnest } = R

const Data = { 
  target : ["a", "b", "c"], 
  count : [1, 2, 3],
}

const data2_applySpec = applySpec({
  result: pipe(props(['target', 'count']), apply(zipWith(repeat)), unnest)
})

const result = data2_applySpec(Data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-rZHvUXcc1zWKsxm7rJ8lVQuIr1oOmm7cShlvpV0gWf0RvbcJN6x96al/Rp2L2BI4a4ZkT2/YfVe/8YvB2UHzQw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```